# How to use phpmyadmin mysql database using terminal in ubuntu 10.4?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Can any one help me to use phpmyadmin mysql database through terminal.

I am using ubuntu 10.4.

I guess the command like this **/opt/var/usr/ mysql**. I'm not sure about it.

Comment: it's not quite clear... you want to access MySQL from the terminal?

Comment: yes.. I want access from terminal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer:**

The Below command used to access phpmyadmin mysql database though terminal

```
/opt/lampp/bin/mysql -uroot -ppassword
```

Answer (score 6):

In terminal just type:

```
mysql -u username -p
```

and afterwards you'll be prompted for your password.

Normally MySQL is added to /bin/ so no need to explicitly give a path to it.

Comment: If i use this command then it will show the message like           **The program 'mysql' can be found in the following packages:
 * mysql-client-core-5.1
 * mysql-client-5.0
 * mysql-cluster-client-5.1
Ask your administrator to install one of them**

Comment: Well then it seems you don't have it installed... Run `sudo apt-get install mysql-server` to install MySQL server... then `sudo apt-get install php5-mysql` to install the php5-MySQL connector and `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin` to install phpMyAdmin.

Comment: ok. But phpmyadmin already is in my machine. Now I can access through below command..  **/opt/lamp/bin/mysql -uroot**  Thanks.

Comment: Ah a lamp installation... I see... Well anyway, I advise you to create another user account with limited privileges and not use the root one. So your problem is solved now?

Comment: Cool no prob. Then you can choose my answer as the good one :) Have fun!