# Mess up between mysql server and phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

After I installed XAMP on my ubuntu 12.10 it was working fine with mysql.

I could start `mysql- sudo mysql -uroot -p`. I connet it using `127.0.0.1:3306`

Recently I installed phpmyadmin. When I start it it shows access denied.
I got solution from web:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
sudo /etc/init.d/proftpd stop
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Now I start php myadmin it starts but now I could not connect with mysql on terminal.

Additionally phpmyadmin database does not shows all existing databse on mysql.

CAn anyone tell me what's going on here?

Comment: because of `/etc/init.d/mysql stop` i think

Comment: actually you have installed new instance of lamp leaving the old apache mysql behind, your old databases were in the old mysql and this phpmyadmin points to the new installed lamp's mysql

Comment: what you need to do is just and just install phpmyadmin over your old apache and mysql, have a look at this link http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/09/install-phpmyadmin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question may help to connect through Terminal.

[How to use phpmyadmin mysql database using terminal in ubuntu 10.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349258/how-to-use-phpmyadmin-mysql-database-using-terminal-in-ubuntu-10-4)

The Below command used to access phpmyadmin mysql database though terminal

```
/opt/lampp/bin/mysql -uusername -ppassword
```

phpmyadmin contains database files in **/opt/lampp/var/mysql** location. Your old mysql server  may contains the database files in different location. That's y you unable to get the database list.